# Functional Programming with Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure, user-defined-functions

gurus

Here's a question for you: I am working on a clojure program that
involves passing functions to functions.

I have something like:

```
(defn funct-op [args]
      ((first args) 
       (second args) 
       (last args)   )

(funct-op '(+ 2 2))
```

How can I coax **funct-op** into giving me **4** rather than the **2** I am
currently getting? I may need to pass a function to a macro as my
project progresses. Any tips on how to do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to turn the '+' into a function you can use resolve. This should work on core functions, but you may need ns-resolve for custom functions. You can then use apply to pass the rest of the arguments to that function.

`(defn funct-add [args] (apply (resolve (first args)) (rest args)))`

Not sure what your end goal really is but I think that is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. A discussion of my end goals are better suited for another question(or does SO allow me to nest questions)?

Answer (score 4):

What is `funct-add` *really* supposed to do? What if it was `(funct-add '(- 2 2))`?

Anyway, consider [apply](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/11/25/clojure-the-apply-function/), even wrapped up:

```
(defn apply-wrapper [args]
   (apply (first args) (rest args)))

; note use of of the [...] form
(apply-wrapper [+ 2 2]) ; => 4
(apply-wrapper [- 2 2]) ; => 0
```

Comparing these forms may be enlightening:

```
(+ 1 2)   ; 3
'(+ 1 2)  ; (+ 1 2)
[+ 1 2]   ; [#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@a8bf33> 1 2]
```

Note how the last one was evaluated; it is not just a "literal list" -- no symbol there anymore! :-)

Happy coding.

Comment: `funct-add` is supposed to take an _unevaluated list of arguments_, evaluate it and _yield_ the result. So `(funct-add '(- 2 2))` will yield **0**. In general `(funct-add '(binary-op operand1 operand2))`, where **binary-op** can be **+**, **-**, or any _operator that takes two arguments_ using prefix notation. Thanks.

Comment: @tscala I think the point is why is "add" in the name if it does more than add

Comment: Also remember that you don't have to quote a list just to keep from evaluating the entire form. If you'd like to evaluate the contents, but not the form as a function call, you can use `list`. `(list + 1 2)`. Of course, it is by far better to just use a vector.

Comment: @AdrianMouat you do make a good point. I should edit the post to reflect the generality I'm aiming for. Thanks.

Comment: @Rayne if vector arg as in `(funct-add [+ 2 2])`, this is not the behavior I am looking for. Otherwise, an example? Thanks.

Comment: @tscala Then `resolve` as per nickmbailey's answer to resolve the symbol or `eval` ("eval is evil") to evaluate the form. Note that `resolve` will yield a function (in this case) which can be applied. If you wish to make your own "form evaluator" then remember, it's just a bunch of lists ;-)

Comment: @pst I've selected nickmbailey's solution(clicked on the arrow) as what I'm looking for. I'm not quite sure what else I do but I will like to thank everyone that gave answers and suggestions.

Comment: @tscala No worries ;-) Happy clojure'ing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, these things?

```
(defn funct-op [f list]
  (apply f list))

(funct-op + '(1 2));=>3
```